# How to send parameter to action method from java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In controller (imagesController) I have 'crop' action get and post. I am trying to send string in it but not working. I am using replace to load view in iFrame but how to post some parameter to it?

```
myIframe.location.replace('images/crop');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myIframe.location.replace('images/crop?someParam=someValue');
```

As far as POST is concerned, forget about it using the `location` property, tat works only with GET requests. If you want to perform a POST request you need either a form submission or an AJAX request.